# Multivariate polynomial fit on soccer data

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, interpolation

I have some data to which I try to fit three polynomials. I've fitted polys to each of the three columns Home,Draw and Away induvidually. The problem is that there is a constraint that

> Home+Draw+Away=1

The following code calculates the polynomial coefficients for each of the columns.

```
home_coeffs = polyfit(match_rating, y_home,1)
draw_coeffs = polyfit(match_rating, y_draw,2)
away_coeffs = polyfit(match_rating, y_away,2)
```

How can I enforce the constraint or reformulate the problem as a multivariable polynomial fit?

```
    Home    Draw    Away
MatchRating             
-26     0.000000    0.000000    1.000000
-24     0.000000    0.000000    1.000000
-22     0.500000    0.000000    0.500000
-21     0.111111    0.333333    0.555556
-20     0.250000    0.000000    0.750000
-19     0.500000    0.333333    0.166667
-18     0.100000    0.000000    0.900000
-17     0.111111    0.222222    0.666667
-16     0.187500    0.375000    0.437500
-15     0.240000    0.120000    0.640000
-14     0.272727    0.272727    0.454545
-13     0.214286    0.250000    0.535714
-12     0.219512    0.463415    0.317073
-11     0.333333    0.214286    0.452381
-10     0.208955    0.238806    0.552239
-9  0.357143    0.285714    0.357143
-8  0.430556    0.291667    0.277778
-7  0.283784    0.405405    0.310811
-6  0.288462    0.298077    0.413462
-5  0.402299    0.218391    0.379310
-4  0.379630    0.259259    0.361111
-3  0.420561    0.317757    0.261682
-2  0.426752    0.292994    0.280255
-1  0.452174    0.260870    0.286957
0   0.419118    0.330882    0.250000
1   0.553957    0.251799    0.194245
2   0.514925    0.268657    0.216418
3   0.483333    0.308333    0.208333
4   0.465347    0.326733    0.207921
5   0.575758    0.202020    0.222222
6   0.587500    0.212500    0.200000
7   0.584615    0.230769    0.184615
8   0.594203    0.275362    0.130435
9   0.609375    0.312500    0.078125
10  0.714286    0.122449    0.163265
11  0.780000    0.160000    0.060000
12  0.769231    0.128205    0.102564
13  0.764706    0.117647    0.117647
14  0.653846    0.230769    0.115385
15  0.826087    0.130435    0.043478
16  0.500000    0.375000    0.125000
17  1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
18  1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
19  0.714286    0.142857    0.142857
20  1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
21  0.666667    0.333333    0.000000
22  1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
26  1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

The plots I've produced here:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scipy.optimize.leastsq()`. Here is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np

txt = """    Home    Draw    Away
-26     0.000000    0.000000    1.000000
-24     0.000000    0.000000    1.000000
-22     0.500000    0.000000    0.500000
-21     0.111111    0.333333    0.555556
-20     0.250000    0.000000    0.750000
-19     0.500000    0.333333    0.166667
-18     0.100000    0.000000    0.900000
-17     0.111111    0.222222    0.666667
-16     0.187500    0.375000    0.437500
-15     0.240000    0.120000    0.640000
-14     0.272727    0.272727    0.454545
-13     0.214286    0.250000    0.535714
-12     0.219512    0.463415    0.317073
-11     0.333333    0.214286    0.452381
-10     0.208955    0.238806    0.552239
-9  0.357143    0.285714    0.357143
-8  0.430556    0.291667    0.277778
-7  0.283784    0.405405    0.310811
-6  0.288462    0.298077    0.413462
-5  0.402299    0.218391    0.379310
-4  0.379630    0.259259    0.361111
-3  0.420561    0.317757    0.261682
-2  0.426752    0.292994    0.280255
-1  0.452174    0.260870    0.286957
0   0.419118    0.330882    0.250000
1   0.553957    0.251799    0.194245
2   0.514925    0.268657    0.216418
3   0.483333    0.308333    0.208333
4   0.465347    0.326733    0.207921
5   0.575758    0.202020    0.222222
6   0.587500    0.212500    0.200000
7   0.584615    0.230769    0.184615
8   0.594203    0.275362    0.130435
9   0.609375    0.312500    0.078125
10  0.714286    0.122449    0.163265
11  0.780000    0.160000    0.060000
12  0.769231    0.128205    0.102564
13  0.764706    0.117647    0.117647
14  0.653846    0.230769    0.115385
15  0.826087    0.130435    0.043478
16  0.500000    0.375000    0.125000
17  1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
18  1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
19  0.714286    0.142857    0.142857
20  1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
21  0.666667    0.333333    0.000000
22  1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
26  1.000000    0.000000    0.000000"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0)

from scipy import optimize

x = df.index.values
y1 = df.Home.values
y2 = df.Draw.values
y3 = df.Away.values

def f(params):
    a, b, c, d, e = params
    oy1 = a + b*x
    oy2 = c + d*x + e*x*x
    oy3 = 1.0 - oy1 - oy2
    return oy1, oy2, oy3

def error(params):
    oy1, oy2, oy3 = f(params)
    e1 = y1 - oy1
    e2 = y2 - oy2
    e3 = y3 - oy3
    return np.concatenate((e1, e2, e3))

params = optimize.leastsq(error, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1])[0]

oy1, oy2, oy3 = f(params)

import pylab as pl
pl.plot(x, y1)
pl.plot(x, oy1)

pl.plot(x, y2)
pl.plot(x, oy2)

pl.plot(x, y3)
pl.plot(x, oy3)
```

here is the output:

[image]

here is the params:

```
[  4.97460839e-01   1.71243863e-02   2.74933473e-01  -1.58439751e-03
  -3.48952223e-04]
```

Comment: Yes indeed, lovely! However, I cannot see how to import from scipy? I copy-pasted that code into an ipython notebook but 

`ImportError: No module named scipy`

Comment: *facepalm*

Thanks, I really apprechiate this!